# Django: validating forms declared on client side with angularjs

Tags: python, django, validation, formset

I'd like to replicate something similar to the ModelForm, but for many instances (through an array of dictionaries).

If we have

models.py

```
 Article(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField()
     author = models.CharField()
```

and modelforms.py

```
ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Article
```

I can do

```
>> form = ArticleForm({"title": "example title", "author": "example author"})
>> form.is_valid()
True
```

Now, suppose I have an array of dictionaries [{"title": "example title 1", "author": "example author 1"}, {"title": "example title 2", "author": "example author 2"}, {"title": "example title 3", "author": "example author 3"}] that was passed by a post call, I'd like to do form validation with the passed info.

Is there a way to do it all in one go so I can if all of them are valid? Or is list comprehension with modelforms my best workaround? I know of formsets but I'm using client side forms and want to validate the forms on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is list comprehension with modelforms my best workaround?

Yes, or `map`s and `filter`s:

```
valid_forms = filter(lambda fm: fm.is_val(), 
                     map(ArticleForm, some_list_of_dictionaries))
```

If you're using Python3, this will return a generator object, which you can iterate over or you can immediately evaluate using something like the following:

```
valid_forms = list(filter(lambda fm: fm.is_val(), 
                          map(ArticleForm, some_list_of_dictionaries)))
```

If you're only interested in finding out if all of them are valid, you can do:

```
all_forms_are_valid = all(lambda fm: fm.is_val(), 
                          map(ArticleForm, some_list_of_dictionaries))
```

But if you want to access them later on (and you're on Python3), it seems like a list comprehension is a better way to go because otherwise you're inefficiently building the same generator object twice.

**Edit with a question:**

> Is there any difference between `map(ArticleForm, some_list_of_dictionaries)` and `[ArticleForm(dict) for dict in some_list_of_dictionaries]`?

It depends on if you're using Python3 or not. In Python3, `map` will return a generator while in Python2, it will evaluate the expression (return a `list`), whereas either will evaluate the complete list  in your list comprehension.

In Python3, there can be some advantages to doing something like this:

```
valid_forms = filter(lambda fm: fm.is_valid(),
                     map(ArticleForm, some_list_of_dictionaries))
```

Because you end up with a generator that pulls data through it instead of first evaluating into a list with the `map` and then evaluating into another list with the `filter`.

**Edit 2:**

Forgot to mention that you can turn your list comprehension into a generator by using parentheses instead:

```
all_valid = all(ArticleForm(fm).is_valid() for fm in some_list_of_dictionaries)
```

Comment: Is there any difference between map(ArticleForm, some_list_of_dictionaries) and [ArticleForm(dict) for dict in some_list_of_dictionaries]?